# Linq lambda expression throwing error if result set is null

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

In my project I need to select one row values using linq

```
try
{
return database.Employees.Where(x => id.Equals(x.ID)).Single();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException Ix)
{
    throw;
}
```

using that I will get corresponding row values through entity object.But it is throwing an error if the result set is empty.The problem is in my project Exception is must to be logged.
How can I manage this code with out going to exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Single()` which is [*documented*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) to throw an exception if there are no results. If you don't want that behaviour, don't use that method :)

If you use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) it will return null if there are no results. It will still throw an exception if there are multiple results, however. Alternatively you could use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid this.

Note that you can specify a predicate in `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` as well, so you don't need a `Where` call first:

```
return database.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => id.Equals(x.ID));
```

Comment: Ok,For the entire row i used First().Any suggestion instead of first() ?

Comment: @ROBIN: Sure - `FirstOrDefault`. Given your other comment, it sounds like you may have misunderstood the difference between `Single` and `First`...

Comment: yes,i think some misunderstanding is there.Anyway thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
  return database.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => id.Equals(x.ID));


}
catch (InvalidOperationException Ix)
{
  throw;
}
```

Comment: In my knowledge single is for one column and First() is for one row.So How to handle exception from first() ?

Comment: @ROBIN: Your "knowledge" is incorrect. Both `Single` and `First` extract a single element from a sequence - the only difference is that `Single` goes bang if there are multiple elements to choose from, whereas `First` returns the first one.

Comment: @ROBIN Jon is right here.One more thing if you are using single and there is more than one row come after filter then you also got error,on the other hand in first you have to select only first row from group of rows.